# System.Net.HttpListener - Windows 10 - Method to take over the port used by different user on same machine but same application

Tags: c#, .net, httplistener

I have requirement where under windows 10, 2 different users on same machine (switched by windows feature "switch user") must be able to run same application.

Constructor runs following code and there is an issue on second user.

```
hl = new HttpListener();
hl.Prefixes.Add($"http://localhost:xx/"); // xx is constant port #
hl.Start(); // exception : Failed to listen on prefix beacause it conflicts with an existing registration on the machine
```

As expected, the port is already in use, so the exception gets triggered.

What can I do to resolve this issue so the "currently logged in user" gets to use the port?

Thank you very much in advanced.

Comment: You need to run a service and have service open the port.  The have users connect to the service.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the SessionSwitch event and checked the reason.
Upon ConsoleDisconnect, I closed the Listener, and I reinitialized it once it is ConsoleConnect.